# Cookie is not set while redirecting in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect to a different domain, so the below code is redirecting properly, but when I check the cookie the cookie is not set in the redirected URL.

What might be the issue? I am using Django 1.8.17.

```
@permission_required('users.page_live', login_url='/admin/')
def users_view(request):
    try:
        user_list = UsersConfig.objects.get(meta_key="ALLOWED_USERS")
        user_list = [int(x) for x in user_list.meta_value.split(",")]
        sessionId = 0

        if request.user.id not in user_list:
            redirect_url = "http://mes.meta.in/admin"
            try:
                if settings.ENV == 'PROD':
                    
                    redirect_url = "https://data-frontend.production.us.mes.cloud/"
                else:
                    redirect_url = 'https://data-frontend.staging.us.me.s/'
                response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                response = HttpResponseRedirect("/admin")
        else:
            redirect_url = "http://mes.meta.in/admin"
            try:
                if settings.ENV == 'PROD':
                    redirect_url = "https://data-frontend.production.us.mes.cloud/"
                else:
                    redirect_url = 'https://data-frontend.staging.us.me.s/'
                response = HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
            except Exception as e:
                print e
                response = HttpResponseRedirect("/admin")

        max_age = 172800
        expires = datetime.strftime(datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=max_age), "%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
        if settings.ENV == 'PROD':
            response['Set-Cookie'] = 'mes_wr_session_id=' + sessionId + '; domain=mes.in; port=80; path=/'
        else:
            response.set_cookie(key="mes_wr_session_id", value=sessionId, max_age=max_age, expires=expires)

    except Exception as e:
        print e

    return response
```

Comment: The domain you've specified for your cookie (`mes.in`) doesn't appear to be the domain you're redirecting to. Also third party cookies are often blocked by browsers/privacy extensions.

Comment: So what should i do in this case, instead of mes.in i should pass data-frontend ?

Comment: tried this one as suggested but didn't worked                         response.set_cookie(key="mes_wr_session_id", value=sessionId, max_age=max_age, expires=expires, path='/' domain="data-frontend.staging.us.me.s/") for checking in localhost, is there anything to update in this one ?

Comment: You need to use the domain that you're redirecting to. `data-frontend.staging.us.me.s/` is not a domain, it's a URL because you've appended a slash. The domain is the URL without the slash.

Comment: I added without slash response.set_cookie(key="mes_wr_session_id", value=sessionId, max_age=max_age, expires=expires, path='/' domain="data-frontend.staging.us.me.s") that also didn't worked

Comment: When i checked the headers of the link once i click for redirect for set_cookie this is what its coming mes_wr_session_id=0; Domain=data-frontend.staging.us.me.s"; expires=Fri, 31-Jan-2020 06:32:48 GMT; Max-Age=172800; Path=/